# AngularJS Provider doesn't accept ES6 function declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, function-expression

I've been trying to rewrite some code of ours to comply with ES6 and have encountered the following issue.

> angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:pget] Provider 'books' must define $get factory method.

This is when I write the provider object in this code.

```
(() => {
    const app = angular.module('app', []);

    const books = () => { // Error is here
        let includeVersionInTitle = false;

        this.$get = () => {
            const appName = "Book Logger";
            const appDesc = "Track which books you read.";
            let version = "1.0";

            appName = (includeVersionInTitle) ? (appName += " " + version) : appName;

            return {
                appName: appName,
                appDesc: appDesc
            }
        };

        this.setIncludeVersionInTitle = (value) => {
            includeVersionInTitle = value;
        };
    };

    app.provider("books", [books]);
})();
```

When I change `const books = () => { ... }` to this, `const books = function() { ... }`. It'll work and not throw that error.

I thought that `const a = function() { ... }` and `const a = () => { ... }` where the same thing? Why does it throw this error out?

Comment: An arrow function is not a constructor. It will never get its `this` be a new "instance" when it is called.

Comment: No, they are not the same thing. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions do not have their own "this", but use that of the surrounding code.  You must use a traditional function.

```
this.$get = function() {
```

You can check out a deeper explanation here:

https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/

Comment: So essentially, I'm creating a method on the `global` object, and not the `provider`? That's why I'm getting `Provider 'books' must define $get factory method.`